# DotNetCoreCLI@2 get project name

Tags: azure-pipelines

I am using DotNetCoreCLI@2 publish task in my Azure build pipeline to publish multiple projects binaries.
In the arguments param, I would like to use the project name in the output folder path.

Is it possible to get the project name when this task is running and pass it as param in arguments?

For example:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet publish'
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '-o testpath/{**name-of-the-project**}'
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to get the project name when this task is running and pass it as param in arguments?

The answer is yes.

According to the document [.NET Core CLI task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#publish-projects-to-specified-folder), add `modifyOutputPath` as a input as below and check.

> Publish projects to specified folder：
>
> ```
> # Publish projects to specified folder.
> - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
>   displayName: 'dotnet publish'
>   inputs:
>     command: 'publish'
>     publishWebProjects: false
>     projects: '**/*.csproj'
>     arguments: '-o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Output'
>     zipAfterPublish: true
>     modifyOutputPath: true
> ```

[image]

Comment: Hi Leo, Say suppose I have a folder hierarchy like this: WebApis\Order\Api\Order.Api.csproj. If I follow your solution, it will create Api.zip but I want to create Order.Api.zip. I want to create the zip with the name of the project (csproj) not the folder.

Comment: @ViBi, Got it, thanks for your reply. If you are in this case, I am afraid we could not use the project name as variable for the dotnet task, that is because the $(projectname) is the property for the MSBuild, could not use by the Azure devops directly.